# How do I use array - bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I have too much variable like this:

```
var1="FACEBOOK"
var2="TWITTER"
var3="INSTAGRAM"
...
```

And I need to find last line about my variables like this:

```
var1_last=$(tail -n +1 logfile.txt | awk '$9 ~ "FACEBOOK" {print $0}' | tail -n1)
```

And I need to change this output like this:

```
day=${var1_last:8:2}
month=${var1_last:4:3}
year=${var1_last:20:4}
hour=${var1_last:11:2}
min=${var1_last:14:2}

if [ "$month" == "Jan" ];then
month=01
...
```

But I dont have just few variable, I have so many variable and I need to do that for all variables. I can do copy/paste all lines, and change var1 to var2, but its so hard.

How can I do this with array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not at all clear what you are asking, but I guess this could at least help nudge you in the right direction.

```
array=("FACEBOOK" "TWITTER" "INSTAGRAM")
for var in "${ARRAY[@]}"; do
    last="$(tail -n +1 logfile.txt | awk '$9 ~"'"$var"'"' | tail -n 1)"
    :
done
```

The whole thing makes more sense as a pure Awk script, though.

```
awk 'BEGIN { a[1] = "FACEBOOK"; a[2] = "TWITTER"; a[3] = "INSTAGRAM" }
    1==NR { next }
    $9 in a { b[$9] = $0 }   # parse the line into individual fields here
    END { for (k in b) print b[k] }' logfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array[0]="$var1"
array[1]="$var2"
array[2]="$var3"
.
.
```

Then use "for" to loop over all cells in that array and pick the part you want. Notice that index starts from zero i.e. first cell in any array is in index zero.